# Array.push throwing TypeError for array.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function capitalizeFirst(arr, new_arr) {
    if (arr.length === 0) return new_arr;
    let str = arr.pop();
    console.log(str);
    return capitalizeFirst(arr, new_arr.push(str));
}
```

Here is my code. The goal is to practice recursion with this exercise. I am giving the function the following parameters

`capitalizeFirst(['car','taco','banana'], []);`

new_arr is clearly an array. Why is the push method not working on it? Also, when I change my return statement to

`return capitalizeFirst(arr, [].push(str));`

and follow along with chrome debugger, the number 1 keeps getting passed to the array instead of the arr.pop() value. What is causing this behavior? I haven't added in the implementation to capitalize the first letter yet either. That was just going to be a replace() call inside my push method in case anyone was wondering why my code wasn't doing what the method name proclaimed.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From W3C:

> The push() method adds new items to the end of an array, and returns the new length.

The first loop should be fine, but because you're passing `.push` recursively, the second loop sees a number instead of an array because `push` returns a number.

Push on it's own line, then pass just the new_arr as the param.

```
function capitalizeFirst(arr, new_arr) {
    if (arr.length === 0) return new_arr;
    let str = arr.pop();
    console.log(str);
    new_arr.push(str); // the return of .push is the array length, which is not needed. 
    return capitalizeFirst(arr, new_arr); // pass the full array into this function, making it recursive
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, your error is mainly because `push()` returns the length of the array after the element was pushed on it, and this will be passed as argument on the recursive call instead of an array:

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and **returns** the new length of the array.

A simple fix will be next:

```js
function capitalizeFirst(arr, new_arr)
{
    if (arr.length === 0)
        return new_arr;

    let str = arr.pop();

    // Added code to capitalize first letter.
    str = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);    

    new_arr.push(str);

    return capitalizeFirst(arr, new_arr);
}

console.log(capitalizeFirst(['car','taco','banana'], []));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you `console.log(typeof new_arr)` you get `number` as answer.

The reason is that the return value of `arr.push()` is the index the value was pushed to, not the new array. So your works if you do this:

```
function capitalizeFirst(arr, new_arr) {
    if (arr.length === 0) return new_arr;
    let str = arr.pop();
    new_arr.push(str);
    return capitalizeFirst(arr, new_arr);
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_push.asp (see return value section)

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
>   returns the new length of the array.

```js
function capitalizeFirst(arr, new_arr) {
    console.log("Type of new_arr : ",typeof(new_arr),":", new_arr);
    if (arr.length === 0) return new_arr;
    let str = arr.pop();
    console.log(str);
    console.log("Push returns Length", new_arr.push(str))
    return capitalizeFirst(arr, new_arr.push(str));
}


function correctCapitalizeFirst(arr, new_arr) {
    console.log("Type of new_arr : ",typeof(new_arr),":", new_arr);
    if (arr.length === 0) return new_arr;
    let str = arr.pop();
    console.log(str);
    new_arr.push(str);
    return correctCapitalizeFirst(arr, new_arr);
}
console.log("--------------- Correct -----------------");
correctCapitalizeFirst(['car','taco','banana'], []);
console.log("--------------- Incorrect ---------------");
capitalizeFirst(['car','taco','banana'], []);
```