# Array.push() is not a function - attempting to push numbers to an array, but the array has changed type

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion, typeerror

I'm 3 months into Javascript, and find it has no respect for its own declarations.

I have declared an empty array, and want to push a number to it, so that it returns an array of numbers (i.e., separable). However, I am told .push() is not a function. Concat() will not work either, and of course += ruins the algorithm.

How do I get it to accept each next value into an array?
I have tried using 'new Array()', but it does not assist.

Similar to, but not the same as, [Array.push throwing TypeError for array.push is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55423187/array-push-throwing-typeerror-for-array-push-is-not-a-function)

In brief:

```
const fn = (n) => {
  let factors = [];
  let index = 1;

  while (n % 2 == 0){
    let out = 2 ** index;
    factors.push(out);
    index++;
    n /= 2;
  }
}
```

This returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: factors.push is not a function
```

(I have left out a lot of code that does not affect the issue.)

Edit update: WIP. Apparently, the loop this is enclosed in has an effect, as do other variable declarations.

With any luck, I will return with a different question, having solved the initial problem.

Comment: The problem could not be found with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Nested loops seems to have been the *actual* problem, which means others could not reproduce.

```
const fn = (m, n) => {
let factors = [];
let index = 1;
for (let i = m; i <= n; i++) {
while (i % 2 == 0){
  let out = 2 ** index;
  factors.push(out);
  index++;
  n /= 2;
  } 
}}
```

For unknown reasons, this causes a type mismatch. The declaration of the array appears to be the cause.

This problem has been abandoned as the initiating function was completed by other methods.

Answer (score -1):

**Here!** its working well, what might went wrong on your side?

```js
const fn = (n) => {
  let index = 1;
  let factors = [];
  while (n % 2 == 0){
    let out = 2 ** index;
    factors.push(out);
    index++;
    n /= 2;
  }
  return factors
}


 document.write(fn(400));
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. Why should the changes you made solve `push` not being a function? I couldn’t reproduce the issue in the first place, and your changes seem of take place only **after** the call to push that the OP says doesn’t work.

Comment: I have discovered that apparently, wrapping it all in a for() loop makes a difference. I do not understand why, but I believe I shall edit the question.

Comment: However, since I'm getting a different error by *only* wrapping it in a for loop, we'll call that progress.